# Get CodeName with Protected VBA project - Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, automation, password-protection, vba

I have a UDF:

```
Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, Optional WB As Workbook) As Worksheet
    If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    With WB
        Set SheetFromCodeName = .Sheets(.VBProject.VBComponents(aName).Properties("Index"))
    End With
End Function
```

And is called via this code:

`Set TargetAnalysis = SheetFromCodeName(AnalysisSheetCodeName)`

My VBA project is password protected so this lines causes an error and I have to un-protect the VBA project which is not allowed for user.

Is there a way (work-around) to:

- Unprotect VBA Project
- Do my Stuff
- Protect it again without closing and opening the Workbook

Something similar to:

```
Sub Foo()
  Dim passKey As String
  passKey = "123"
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect passKey

  // Foo-Related stuff here

  ActiveSheet.Protect passKey, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
End Sub
```

In case this can't be done, are there any protection method other than password ?

Comment: Not possible. The best you could do is probably sendkeys, but I'd advise against it

Comment: I know about sendkeys method to unprotect the VBA project and even more to protect it, but once it is unprotected you have to reopen the workbook so that the protection works again, unlike the protect/unprotect of sheets/workbooks.

Comment: *"I know about sendkeys method"*. Then **say so** in your question. Or are you expecting us to keep playing this game with you until we come up with something you don't know? That said, we're not going to come up with a magic solution to this one anyway. Excel/VBA has its limitations.